# Adding a column in csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I have hundreds of .csv files with 40 rows and 34 columns each. I want to add a column at position 26 and column 26-34 should shift to make space for the new one. First row of the file is empty and second row has the titles and rest have the values. The new column should have a title in row two and rest of the rows can be zero.
Please help me with this code in python.

```
import csv

infilename = r'C:\Users\Sulabh Kumra\Desktop\input.csv'
outfilename = r'C:\Users\Sulabh Kumra\Desktop\output.csv'

with open(infilename, 'rb') as fp_in, open(outfilename, 'wb') as fp_out:
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=",")
    headers = next(reader)  # read first row

    writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for row in reader:
        row.append(row[2])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: import csv

infilename = r'C:\Users\Sulabh Kumra\Desktop\input.csv'
outfilename = r'C:\Users\Sulabh Kumra\Desktop\output.csv'

with open(infilename, 'rb') as fp_in, open(outfilename, 'wb') as fp_out:
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=",")
    headers = next(reader)  # read first row

    writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for row in reader:
        row.append(row[2])
        writer.writerow(row)

Comment: Drop that in the original question, please. :)

Comment: I am new to csv using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting into a python list is pretty easy: `some_list[2:2] = ['stuff','to','insert']`

So your code would look like the following:

```
import csv

infilename = r'C:\Users\Sulabh Kumra\Desktop\input.csv'
outfilename = r'C:\Users\Sulabh Kumra\Desktop\output.csv'

with open(infilename, 'rb') as fp_in, open(outfilename, 'wb') as fp_out:
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=",")
    writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=",")

    blank_line = next(reader)
    writer.writerow(blank_line)

    headers = next(reader)  # read title row

    headers[26:26] = ['New Label']

    writer.writerow(headers)

    for row in reader:
        row[26:26] = [0]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am able to understand this code and it makes sense. But it gives the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/addcol", line 9, in <module>
    writer.writerow(blank_line)
NameError: name 'writer' is not defined

Comment: Sorry about that, the writer initialization wasn't happening early enough.